# By using a dynamic proxy, is there a way I can return an object whose type doesn't match the method signature of the proxied interface?

Tags: java, netty

I think the short answer may be no, but I'm hoping I can get alternative suggestions.  Assume I have a data object and a data service.  The data service is an interface and has the following method.

```java
public Data getData();
```

I'm creating a proxy for the service using the following invocation handler plus Netty to do what I'd call asynchronous rpc.  The proxy is on the client side.

```java
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    // Convert the call into an async request that returns a ListenableFuture
    APCRequest request = new APCRequest(serviceType, method, args);
    ListenableFuture future = apcClient.asyncMessage(request);

    // This blocks until the future finishes
    return future.get();
}
```

This works fine.  However, if my client is a UI, I end up wrapping the service call in something like a SwingWorker.  I'd prefer to come up with a way of returning the ListenableFuture that I already have sitting there.  Is there any way I can accomplish that without creating a separate, asynchronous service API.  For example:

```java
public ListenableFuture<Data> getData();
```

If I could have my InvocationHandler return the wrong type, I could use something like this.

```java
public abstract class AsyncServiceCall<S, D> { // S = service type, D = expected doCall return type
    protected final S service;

    protected AsyncServiceCall(Class<S> serviceType, APCClient client) {
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(client);

        // The true tells the proxyFactory we're expecting a ListenableFuture<D>
        // rather than the real return type.
        service = proxyFactory.createProxy(serviceType, true);
    }

    // Sub-classes would make a normal method call using this.  For
    // example, service.getData()
    public abstract Object doCall();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListenableFuture<D> execute() {
        return (ListenableFuture<D>) doCall();
    }
```

Is there another way of accomplishing what I want?  Performance isn't an issue for me, so blocking until the proxy can get the return value from the future is still an option if there's no simple way of doing what I want.  It just seems like a waste since I want an asynchronous call in the UI anyway.

Keeping my service API simple is more of a priority than anything.  I want to be able to prototype using a simple service provider that instantiates service implementations directly and plug in my remoting protocol / server that's using dynamic proxies / Netty late in the development cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your API simple then I would suggest providing *only* the async API in the interface - it's much easier to wrap up a synchronous implementation in an asynchronous API than vice-versa.

```
public interface DataService {
  public ListenableFuture<Data> getData();
}

public abstract class LocalDataService implements DataService {
  public ListenableFuture<Data> getData() {
    SettableFuture<Data> result = SettableFuture.create();
    try {
      Data theData = computeData();
      result.set(theData);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
      result.setException(e);
    }
    return result;
  }

  protected abstract Data computeData() throws Throwable;
}
```

Comment: Providing _only_ an async API is definitely the correct approach for my situation.  Everything becomes simpler, especially the UI design since an async API makes it clear the calls may be long running.

Comment: Note however that in my example above the `LocalDataService` method does block until the computation is complete, even though the interface is nominally asynchronous. It would probably be better to implement it in terms of an Executor so it is truly asynchronous and the caller knows that they won't be blocked.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I wouldn't use your example verbatim since having a `Future` that blocks internally would likely be a source of confusion.  I would use a normal `FutureTask` instead.  Thank you for the help.